# One Controller showing 500 Internal Server Error Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have completed a project in CodeIgniter. It was working perfectly with my localhost.
When I uploaded it to my Web Server, one of the Controllers always show '500 Internal Server Error'.

I went through several questions in this website, everyone says about .htaccess files, but I have not added any .htaccess files.

Secondly, it was found that one of my libraries (extending Form_Validation) was also being not loaded in the webserver, despite working in the localhost.

Please help.

Comment: First suggestion, check file / folder permissions

Comment: Check your web-server log files.

Comment: What should be permissions? 755 ? now it is 644.

Comment: This is the Web-Server Log File - [Thu Feb 06 09:11:42 2014] [error] [client 117.237.157.86] File does not exist: xxx/500.shtml, referer: xxx/index.php/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are your local and server operating system?

Probably if you use Windows localy and you use linux on server you have difference in case sensitive in some file name.

Windows is not case sensitive.

Check if you have capital letter in your Controller names. For example you shouldn't use **nameOfYourController.php** but **nameofyourController.php**.